# jquery UI slider does not show up (css attached)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Having looked at many similar issues I still can not figure out why I can not display jquery UI slider. Below is my code.

The js file is being loaded and the css file is in the same location. (in the same folder as the html file)

I know jquery ui is loaded because I do not see the alert message. But I still can not see the slider. I tried

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
    PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"/>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         document.body.innerHTML = "ready..."
        //ready();
        if (jQuery.ui) {
            $("#slider").slider()
        } else {
            alert("no jquery ui")
        }
    });
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body id="mainBody">
<div id="slider"></div>
not yet ready...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have the image sprite and is it in the right location?

Comment: The `href` on the css file is not relative to the html file calling it. It's relative to the site.

Comment: You are overwriting the HTML of the entire page with "ready...". That erases all content, including your `div#slider` element.

Comment: @showdev that was the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing all of the HTML (including #slider) in body with "ready...". This makes `$("#slider").slider()` not work because there's no longer a #slider element. A better way to do it would be to wrap "not yet ready..." with a DIV like so:

```
<body id="mainBody">
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="status">not yet ready...</div>
</body>
```

And then replace `document.body.innerHTML = "ready..."` with `$("#status").html("ready...")`

That should do the trick.